# Increase length of custom text field when the field has data

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, data-types, text

I have a custom field on a custom object having text length **50**. This object already has about **10K** records.

My requirement here is to increase the text length to length **255**. But I am not sure if I do that, the value of this field on **10K** records will be reset to blank.

Can you pl help confirming if I have a problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't have a problem with increasing the size of a text field.

If you decrease the size of a text field, the data will be truncated to the new field size.

> Warning: Potential Data Loss
>   Warning Making this change may cause data loss by truncating values that do not meet the new restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

**Increase in field length will not create any issues.**

If you are not sure about the effect, then take backup of records or do the changes first in Full copy sandbox, verify the effect and then change in production.

Again there will be no issues as long as you are not changing the field type.

If you are curious then refer [Notes on Changing Custom Field Types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=notes_on_changing_custom_field_types.htm&language=en&type=0)